# $_GET with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, select, get, where-clause

Here is my code:

```
if ($_GET['u'] == $userid) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uuserid='$userid'"); 
}
```

The $userid variable is defined in the rest of the script and works properly.
My script is script.php and works correctly (it's a table that shows rows from the table toondb).
However, there is a column in my table called uuserid.  My userid is '1'.  So, if you type...

```
script.php?u=1
```

I need it to show you the rows in the database where uuserid='$userid'
It is working when I type script.php?u=1
However, user 620 also has rows in the DB and when I type
script.php?u=620
I get blank results. 
Help, please?  Maybe it's a problem with the query above :)

-- 
update:
My variable actually is MY own userid

```
$userid = ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid']);
```

Therefore, $userid is ALWAYS 1 for me because my userid is 1.  Ugh, I am a doofus right now.
How can I make it so, if you type script.php?u=620.. it plugs 620 into the where clause and will show you all rows in the table where uuserid=620

Thanks!

Comment: Before you figure out which the input variable is and how to use it, read up on database escaping, or the less cumbersome PDO and bound parameters / prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That if means the query will only be executed if the url param == current logged in user, so I'd get rid of that.

```
<?php
//...

if (ctype_digit($_GET['u'])) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM toondb WHERE uuserid={$_GET['u']}"); 
}

?>
```

The mysql functions are about to be deprecated, so start using PDO :D

Comment: Thanks!  This worked like bread and butter.  Not sure what PDO is.. however, I do use mysql_real_escape_string attached to all of my $_POST's.. is that good enough?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() is for escaping strings, not digits which is why I haven't used it above, but then PHP is okay with numbers being treated as strings so it will work. I'm guessing you're just editing the vbulletin source code?

Answer (score 0):

We're lacking an important piece of code: how is the value of $userid computed? I have a feeling it doesn't even reach your query because of your if, that is that $userid is always 1 so any value of $_GET['u'] different than 1 will not satisfy the condition of your if thus not computing the query.

Comment: Omg wow.. I just realized.  $userid is MY userid.  Because the variable is: $userid = ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid']);  So, how can I make it so when you do ToonDatabase.php?u=620, it does the query and adds 620 in for the WHERE clause?

Comment: Then an easy fix would be to remove the if and do the following: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM toondb WHERE uuserid='" . intval($_GET['u']) . "'"); But PLEASE read on prepared statements and sql injections before going down that path.